# PyQt documentation

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have installed *PyQt GPL v4.6.2 for Python v3.1* and *Qt by Nokia v4.6.0 (OpenSource)*, but the documentation in PyQt is not coming up. Example docs are all blank, too.

Would anyone mind writing a step-by-step guide on what links to visit and what procedures must be executed in order to get text to come up for the PyQt documentation?

**Edit:** The programs are running on Windows, and the documentation is not coming up in *PyQt GPL v4.6.2 for Python v3.1 > Examples > PyQt Examples and Demos* and *PyQt GPL v4.6.2 for Python v3.1 > Assistant*. What needs to done to let both programs access the docs?

Comment: How are you trying to open the docs? And what platform?

It's likely that pydoc doesn't work, to begin with...

Comment: I have the same problem by the way on Win7 x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PyQt documentation is exactly as provided on the website, and as
included in the installer. It is not integrated with Assistant (it will be
in a future version). If you want to use Assistant then you can use the Qt
documentation instead (a lot of people do) and translate between C++ and
Python as you read it.

Answer (score 6):

Some out of date answers here. Best resources are:

[The Reference Guide](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/)

and

[The Class Reference Guide](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/classes.html)

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about the standalone docs, but have you also looked at *(this post is a cw, so feel free to edit)*:

[*PyQt's Classes, adapted from the documentation provided with Qt4.*](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/classes.html)

and

[GUI Programming with Python: QT Edition](http://www.commandprompt.com/community/pyqt/book1)?

The last one has some really deep and helpful (at least to a novice I think) advice (for example: [*Python Objects and Qt Objects*](http://www.commandprompt.com/community/pyqt/c2341)) while being a free book.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I need to look at documentation, I just search Google for the specific widget I am interested in.  For example:  [QTreeWidget](http://www.google.com/search?q=QTreeWidget).  Sometimes you get an older version of Qt, but if you click the "similar" link in the search result, you can pretty much always find the page you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the Qt documentation, you should have an app named Assistant. This is a simple-minded browser for a local copy of the Qt doc as found at doc.qt.nokia.com. It is written for C++ but the mental translation to Python is not difficult, and it is nicely formatted and richly cross-linked. I keep Assistant running all the time I'm coding in PyQt4 and find it very helpful.

The PyQt doc, as given at www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/classes.html, is merely this same Nokia text with its formatting and many of the internal links stripped out and edited to python class and function syntax.